# Make android application run on eclipse emulator using the extracted files from the apk

Tags: android, eclipse, emulation, apk

I know how to extract source code and the xml from apk file, after doing that i am left with folders having the source code and xml , my question is , is there any easy way to make those source files run on the eclipse emulator because im really confused as to what goes where. I am struggling to rebuild the code on eclipse. A guidance would be really helpful.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: you can't run the extract source code, because android will generate the R.java file while developing an project and its auto generate file, which is communication xml and java code through dynamic generating int values.

Comment: thank you, but i can still use the source code for reference right?

Comment: ya you can use it for reference, if they used progaurd in that app, you can't use even for reference.

Comment: that was informative , thank you :)

Comment: Are you trying to reverse engineer someone else's APK, or is there another purpose for extracting and running this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt you extracted source from an APK file. Apart from that, the only way to run android applications is to install their respective APK file on a device / on an emulator.

Even if there would be a way to run applications without previous installation of an APK file (e.g. hacking the file system and putting stuff where it should be), using such a way is highly discouraged.

Also, please note that it is not possible to modify the contents of an APK file after it has been build, since every APK file is digitally signed.